# CRM 2013 SP1 On-Premise: "Assembly must be registered in isolation" error despite already a deployment admin

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

As per the title I am a deployment admin but when I try to update a plugin not sandboxed I get the error "Assembly must be registered in isolation"

Typically this means I am not a deployment admin. Only I am... I have triple checked that I have logged in with the correct credentials but I still get that message

I have checked my AD group memberships and I am apart of the CRM PrivReport and PrivUsers groups

Comment: Where is the assembly stored, database, GAC or server?

Comment: Database - i am a sysadmin on the database

Comment: OK, just to confirm, this is happening when you are trying to register a plugin in CRM through plugin registration tool for CRM 2013, and you have also checked that you are Deployment Admin in Deployment manager?

Comment: Correct, this happens when I try to register/update a plugin via plugin registration tool and I am most definitely a deployment manager

Comment: In my experience CRM 2013 plugin registration tool had turned out to be quite buggy, can you try to register assembly with CRM 2015 plugin registration tool?

Comment: I just downloaded it and tried, same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97564/discussion-between-user2727893-and-bojan-borisovski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured it out!

It turns out I was registered in the deployment manager as "domain\someuser" whereas I was in CRM as someuser@domain.

After updating my deployment admin login to match CRM the problem went away!